# NameError: name 'rental_ride_cost' is not defined

Tags: python, функции, return

Необходимо написать несколько локальных функций в составе одной глобальной функции, которая бы возвращала сумму этих локальных функций. Две работают, в последней при попытке вывести результат на печать получаю ошибку:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-95d7ccd25070> in <module>()
     63 
     64 # выводим результат
---> 65 print('Ваше пребывание в {} обойдется Вам в {} у.е. Приятного отдыха!'.format(city, trip_cost(hotel_cost, plane_ride_cost, **rental_ride_cost**)))

NameError: name 'rental_ride_cost' is not defined
```

---

```
# функция trip_cost(hotel_cost, plane_ride_cost, rental_ride_cost)
def trip_cost(hotel_cost, plane_ride_cost, rental_ride_cost):
    '''
        функцию расчета стоимости вашего путешествия
    '''

    # функция hotel_cost() 
    def hotel_cost(num_nights):
        '''
            функция рассчета стоимости всех ночей проведенных в отеле
            принимает на вход кол-во ночей
            стоимость одной ночи КОНСТАНТА (140 у.е.)
        '''
        cost_hotel = 140  
        cost_all_nights = cost_hotel * num_nights
        return cost_all_nights

    # функция plane_ride_cost()
    def plane_ride_cost(city):
        '''
            функция должна вернуть цену перелета в зависимости от места: 
            если это Крым, то перелет обойдется в 120 у.е., 
            если Шри-Ланка - 800 у.е., если Каир - 400 у.е., если Сочи - 120 у.е.
        '''
        cost_flights = cities[city]
        return cost_flights

    # функция rental_ride_cost()
    def rental_ride_cost(days_ride):
        '''
            функция должна рассчитать стоимость аренды авто, 
            если за сутки вы должны оплачивать саму ренту (40 у.е.) + стоимость услуг 
            страхового агентства (+1% от суммарной стоимости услуг каждый следующий день. 
            Т. е. первый день 1% от стоимости, второй - берется 1% от стоимости предыдущего 
            дня (включая 1% за предыдущий день) и т. д. Если вы арендуете на 7 и более дней, 
            то скидка - 50 у.е., если от 3 до 6 дней включительно - 20 у.е. Обе скидки получить сразу нельзя.
        '''
        rent = 40
        days_rental_ride = [rent + rent * 0.01]
        sum_days_rental_ride = 0
        for i in range(days_ride-1):
            days_rental_ride.append(days_rental_ride[i] + days_rental_ride[i] * 0.01)
        for el in days_rental_ride:
            sum_days_rental_ride += el
            if days_ride >= 3 and days_ride <=6:
                sum_for_cost_ride = round(sum_days_rental_ride - 20)
            elif days_ride >= 7:
                sum_for_cost_ride = round(sum_days_rental_ride - 50)
            else:
                sum_for_cost_ride = round(sum_days_rental_ride)
        return sum_for_cost_ride

    # считаем сумму локальных функций и возвращаем значение нашей основной функции    
    cost_trip = hotel_cost(num_nights) + plane_ride_cost(city) + rental_ride_cost(days_ride)
    return cost_trip

# переменные используемые в функциях
# создадим список с названиями мест
cities = {'Крым' : 120, 'Сочи' : 120, 'Шри-Ланка' : 800, 'Каир' : 400}
city = input('Введите название места (города) в который планируете отпуск: ')   # попросим пользователя ввести название города (места)
num_nights = int(input('На сколько дней забронировать отель? '))                # кол-во дней в отеле
days_ride = int(input('Введите кол-во дней аренды авто: '))                     # кол-во дней аренды авто

# выводим результат
print('Ваше пребывание в {} обойдется Вам в {} у.е. Приятного отдыха!'.format(city, trip_cost(hotel_cost, plane_ride_cost, rental_ride_cost)))
```

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/GlassMuffledLaw запускается без ошибок

Comment: Во-первых, это не тот код, в котором ошибка. Во-вторых, перечитайте в учебнике как надо вызывать функцию и сравните с тем, как это у вас.

Comment: Добавил весь код. Перечитывать буду обязательно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы зачем-то в параметрах функции указываете имена, совпадающие с именами внутренних функций - какой в этом смысл не понятно. В параметрах функции должны передаваться значения, от которых зависит результат работы функции - в данном случае логично через параметры передавать то, что вводит пользователь. У вас же эти значения берутся из глобальной области видимости - это не очень хорошо, т.к. если вы вдруг начнете разбивать программу на модули, глобальные переменные перестанут быть доступны для функции.

Пример, как можно сделать:

```
def trip_cost(city, num_nights, days_ride):
    '''
        функцию расчета стоимости вашего путешествия
    '''

    ...  # Тут все остается без изменений

    # считаем сумму локальных функций и возвращаем значение нашей основной функции    
    cost_trip = hotel_cost(num_nights) + plane_ride_cost(city) + rental_ride_cost(days_ride)
    return cost_trip


# переменные используемые в функциях
# создадим список с названиями мест
cities = {'Крым' : 120, 'Сочи' : 120, 'Шри-Ланка' : 800, 'Каир' : 400}


# Обернул в функцию, чтобы вводимые пользователем данные не были доступны глобально
def main():
    city = input('Введите название места (города) в который планируете отпуск: ')   # попросим пользователя ввести название города (места)
    num_nights = int(input('На сколько дней забронировать отель? '))                # кол-во дней в отеле
    days_ride = int(input('Введите кол-во дней аренды авто: '))                     # кол-во дней аренды авто

    # выводим результат
    print('Ваше пребывание в {} обойдется Вам в {} у.е. Приятного отдыха!'.format(city, trip_cost(city, num_nights, days_ride)))


main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно, зачем вашей функции `trip_cost()` параметры? Убрав их, всё работает https://repl.it/repls/ThornyLovingNaturaldocs.

```
# функция trip_cost()
def trip_cost():
    '''
        функцию расчета стоимости вашего путешествия
    '''

    # функция hotel_cost() 
    def hotel_cost(num_nights):
        '''
            функция рассчета стоимости всех ночей проведенных в отеле
            принимает на вход кол-во ночей
            стоимость одной ночи КОНСТАНТА (140 у.е.)
        '''
        cost_hotel = 140  
        cost_all_nights = cost_hotel * num_nights
        return cost_all_nights

    # функция plane_ride_cost()
    def plane_ride_cost(city):
        '''
            функция должна вернуть цену перелета в зависимости от места: 
            если это Крым, то перелет обойдется в 120 у.е., 
            если Шри-Ланка - 800 у.е., если Каир - 400 у.е., если Сочи - 120 у.е.
        '''
        cost_flights = cities[city]
        return cost_flights

    # функция rental_ride_cost()
    def rental_ride_cost(days_ride):
        '''
            функция должна рассчитать стоимость аренды авто, 
            если за сутки вы должны оплачивать саму ренту (40 у.е.) + стоимость услуг 
            страхового агентства (+1% от суммарной стоимости услуг каждый следующий день. 
            Т. е. первый день 1% от стоимости, второй - берется 1% от стоимости предыдущего 
            дня (включая 1% за предыдущий день) и т. д. Если вы арендуете на 7 и более дней, 
            то скидка - 50 у.е., если от 3 до 6 дней включительно - 20 у.е. Обе скидки получить сразу нельзя.
        '''
        rent = 40
        days_rental_ride = [rent + rent * 0.01]
        sum_days_rental_ride = 0
        for i in range(days_ride-1):
            days_rental_ride.append(days_rental_ride[i] + days_rental_ride[i] * 0.01)
        for el in days_rental_ride:
            sum_days_rental_ride += el
            if days_ride >= 3 and days_ride <=6:
                sum_for_cost_ride = round(sum_days_rental_ride - 20)
            elif days_ride >= 7:
                sum_for_cost_ride = round(sum_days_rental_ride - 50)
            else:
                sum_for_cost_ride = round(sum_days_rental_ride)
        return sum_for_cost_ride

    # считаем сумму локальных функций и возвращаем значение нашей основной функции    
    cost_trip = hotel_cost(num_nights) + plane_ride_cost(city) + rental_ride_cost(days_ride)
    return cost_trip

# переменные используемые в функциях
# создадим список с названиями мест
cities = {'Крым' : 120, 'Сочи' : 120, 'Шри-Ланка' : 800, 'Каир' : 400}
city = input('Введите название места (города) в который планируете отпуск: ')   # попросим пользователя ввести название города (места)
num_nights = int(input('На сколько дней забронировать отель? '))                # кол-во дней в отеле
days_ride = int(input('Введите кол-во дней аренды авто: '))                     # кол-во дней аренды авто

# выводим результат
print('Ваше пребывание в {} обойдется Вам в {} у.е. Приятного отдыха!'.format(city, trip_cost()))
```

Comment: Как раз хорошая практика не привязывать работу функций к глобальным объектам, а передавать значения через аргументы. Разрастется программа на 100 страниц кода, начнете разбивать на модули - и все сломается.

Comment: @insolor вы видели что он передавал?

Comment: Я комментирую ваш код, и говорю как делать лучше из соображений хорошей практики. Вы внутри функций берете значения из глобальных переменных - а лучше бы чтобы значения передавались через аргументы.

Comment: @insolor это код автора, а не мой

Comment: С того момента, как вы выпили у функции trip_cost аргументы - считайте что это ваш код.

Comment: @insolor я так не считаю, но не отрицаю полезность комментария для ТС

Comment: всем доброго. спасибо за содействие и советы. работают оба варианта.

Comment: @EugeneSotnikov если вас устраивает ответ, то поставьте галочку под количеством голосов